# Was the Patterson Bigfoot Film Faked?

Tags: history, cryptozoology

On October 20, 1967, Roger Patterson made a video which seared an [image of Bigfoot](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWGYTHK3E30) into the popular consciousness.....

Is that video real?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess the question is really if the film (not video, it was shot on 16MM) shows an actual unknown primate. Probably not.

From a credibility standpoint the film has always been difficult, if only because the [original film has apparently been lost](http://www.themunnsreport.com/tmr%20beginner%20guide.pdf). Therefore, we only know what's in those few seconds of footage. I'd love to know what's on the reel before the famous sequence.

As to the internal evidence you can garner from the film, I'd point to this frame from a later portion of the footage than you usually see. I'm not sure what's up with the sole of the Bigfoot's foot, but it doesn't look organic to me.

[image: bigfootfoot]